# How can i define a post step in declarative syntax that only runs when a build returns to normal

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkins pipelines you can define post steps to run under certain conditions. I am sending notifications of the build status to a mattermost channel and i cant figure out how I can report when a build returns to stable after a failure. The 'changed' option also runs when a build starts failing, but I want to use the 'failure' section for that to differentiate the type of message sent to mattermost.

Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

So, ofcourse right after I post I found a working solution, but im still interested in other options

```
changed {
    script {
        if (env.CHANGE_ID == null && currentBuild.result == null) {

                mattermostSend....
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, declarative pipeline. That's pretty cool! Glad they added that over the way I posted.

Comment: Where did you find documentation of `CHANGE_ID` and `currentBuild`? 

My biggest issue with declarative Pipeline is that the docs are shallow--the ones I have found, anyway.

Comment: Honestly, I cant remember. Just googling. Probably if you google the above piece of code you'll find it. May even have been on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by combining https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226419147-How-can-I-check-previous-build-status-in-a-Pipeline-Script- and a comparison with the current build status.

```
if(currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult().toString() != "SUCCESS" && ( currentBuild.result == "SUCCESS" || currentBuild.result == null ) ) {
    echo "last build failed"
}
```

A few things to note: currentBuild.result defaults to null (which counts as a success), so if it's null or "SUCCESS", then you're good. Also, you'll need to whitelist some of these objects in your groovy script approval page found at jenkinsurl.com/scriptApproval/ (they will appear there after you try to run the script)